# Room 2.5 nested relationships one to one many to one

Tags: android, kotlin, nested, relationship, android-room

## Room

I have a relationship like this
puzzle -> has one-> dialogue -> has many -> dialogue lines

I followed the instructions on
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#kotlin
but still cant get it to work

These are the error that seem to be related:

error: Cannot find the child entity column `puzzleDialogueId` in com.example.puzzleherexamenandroid.data.room.databaseModels.DialogueWithLinesDatabase.

Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase(com.example.puzzleherexamenandroid.data.room.databaseModels.PuzzleDatabase,com.example.puzzleherexamenandroid.data.room.databaseModels.DialogueWithLinesDatabase) -> [param:puzzle -> matched field:puzzle, param:dialogueWithLines -> matched field:unmatched]C:\Users\Jasper\StudioProjects\PuzzleHerexamenAndroid\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\puzzleherexamenandroid\data\room\databaseModels\PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase.java:9: error: Cannot find setter for field.

PuzzleDatabaseDao.java:12: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
java.util.List<com.example.puzzleherexamenandroid.data.room.databaseModels.PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase> puzzle);

### these are my entities

```
@Entity(tableName = "puzzle_table")
@Parcelize
data class PuzzleDatabase (
     @PrimaryKey
     val puzzleId: Int,
     val title: String,
     val prompt: String,
     val answer: String

): Parcelable
```

```
 @Entity(tableName = "dialogue_table")
@Parcelize
data class DialogueDatabase (
    @PrimaryKey
    val dialogueId: Int,
    val prompt: String,
    val char1avatar: String,
    val char2avatar: String,
    val puzzleDialogueId : Int
): Parcelable
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "dialogueLine_table")
@Parcelize
data class DialogueLineDatabase (
    @PrimaryKey
    val dialogueLineId: Int,
    val line: String,
    val speaking: Int,
    val dialogueForeignkeyId: Int
    ): Parcelable
```

### these are the classes for the relationship

```
data class PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase(
    @Embedded val puzzle : PuzzleDatabase,
    @Relation(
        entity = DialogueWithLinesDatabase::class,
        parentColumn = "puzzleId",
        entityColumn = "puzzleDialogueId"
    )
    val dialogueWithLines: DialogueWithLinesDatabase
)
```

```
data class DialogueWithLinesDatabase(
    @Embedded val dialogue:DialogueDatabase,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "dialogueId",
        entityColumn = "dialogueForeignkeyId"
    )
    val dialogueLines: List<DialogueLineDatabase>
)
```

### And this is my doa

```
@Dao
interface PuzzleDatabaseDao {
   @Transaction
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   fun insertAll(puzzle: List<PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase>)

   @Transaction
   @Query("SELECT * from puzzle_table ORDER BY puzzleId DESC")
   fun getAllPuzzles(): LiveData<List<PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase>>
}
```

Comment: The answers seem to only solve your first error. The second is that you cannot use relationship classes as parameters for insert or update methods. 
I believe this is a serious shortcoming in Room, because it makes quite difficult to save complex relationships back to the DB. Even the documentations seems to put this fact under the carpet, because all examples on saving or update are trivial cases such as  insert(user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity property in @Relation should mention the database entity and not the relation-class. Try:

```
data class PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase(
    @Embedded val puzzle : PuzzleDatabase,
    @Relation(
        entity = DialogueDatabase::class,
        parentColumn = "puzzleId",
        entityColumn = "puzzleDialogueId"
    )
    val dialogueWithLines: DialogueWithLinesDatabase
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should change entity `DialogueWithLinesDatabase` with `DialogueDatabase` inside your `PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase` class' Releation definition:

```
data class PuzzleWithDialogueDatabase(
    @Embedded val puzzle : PuzzleDatabase,
    @Relation(
        entity = DialogueDatabase::class, // <- changed
        parentColumn = "puzzleId",
        entityColumn = "puzzleDialogueId"
    )
    val dialogueWithLines: DialogueWithLinesDatabase
)
```